# Is it possible to customise the appearance of the application switcher in Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard

When you press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between applications and the icons appear, is there a way to reduce the size of those large icons?

I have tried 'Witch' but it can not be customised to achieve the above..

Also, I have tried the plenty of links to Mac OS X tweaks but none of them mention this particular feature.

Thanks

James

Answer (score 1):

No, it's just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the application switcher with LiteSwitch X from [Proteron](http://www.proteron.com/), if you'd like. LiteSwitch X is resizable and has several other enhancements.

Comment: yes thankyou, this is perfect. just what I was looking for

Comment: based on the given url, this company no longer exists.. the domain is for sale.